# Fundamental nature of xml namespaces and xsd validation

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

I understand this is a broad question but I wanted to understand the fundamental difference in meaning, with respect to XSD validation, of these two instances:

A: without namespace prefixes -

```
<someRoot xmlns="http://myNamespace">
  <someElement>skjdhf</someElement>
</someRoot>
```

B: with namespace prefixes -

```
<ns0:someRoot xmlns:ns0="http://myNamespace">
  <someElement>skjdhf</someElement>
</ns0:someRoot>
```

I would like to understand the difference between A and B, as even though they appear functionally equivalent, I know they are not. What I am interested in, is what are the two instances "saying" which are different - in what way does the *someElement* element differ in it's relationship to the namespace defined on the *someRoot* element, between the two examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML isn't strong on defining "meaning" (aka "semantics"). The authors of the spec were quite adamant about this: XML defines an expressive syntax, but what it "means" is a matter for the sender and the receiver to agree upon.

Having said that, there's a widespread consensus in the XML community that namespace prefixes are arbitrary and that the recipient of an XML document should accept any prefix that it finds (or no prefix, as in your first example), and so long as it is bound to the right URI, the choice of prefix conveys no information. You can see this, for example in the W3C XML Infoset specification, where it says (in §2.2) "Note that namespace-aware applications should use the namespace name [*] rather than the prefix to identify elements."

This consensus is reflected in the XSD specification: schema validation ignores namespace prefixes.

In all of this, choosing to use no namespace prefix (`<X xmlns="uri"/>`) is an arbitrary choice just as the choice of a specific prefix (`<æ:X xmlns:æ="uri"/>`) is.

[*] the spec uses "namespace name" for what most people refer to as "namespace URI".

However, there is one difference between your two examples that is more significant than the choice of prefix. In your first example, the child element `someElement` has namespace name (URI) `http://myNamespace`. In the second example, the element is in no namespace. That's important (and will affect schema validation); the choice of prefix isn't.

Comment: Thanks Michael - it's actually the last part of your answer which I was interested in: in what way does the *someElement* element differ in it's relationship to the namespace defined on the *someRoot* element between the two examples? If you could expand I would be very grateful.

Comment: `xmlns="uri"` defines a "default" namespace for all unprefixed elements within its scope. `xmlns:p="uri"` defines a namespace for a  elements prefixed "p" within its scope. In your first example the namespace binding applies to the child element, in the second example it doesn't (because the child element is unprefixed).

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Michael. That succinctly explains it for me.